# Dynamic links/redirect with javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, href

Having an annoying small problem.  Cannot find the solution that works tried just about everything i could find from searching here and google.

Purpose of this is to pass them along into a "room" that has been created previously.

Seems like it doesn't matter what i try i cannot get it to load into another page using onclick with an href.  And i know its an easy fix its just something silly i cannot think of.

and sorry if i am not posting my code just right this is my first time asking a question i normally just lurk around for answers.

```
//..Left out <?php and my connect info but it is in my script
//--CLEANUP MY MESS
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('err11');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) $testing[$row[0]] = true;// Gets a list of tables in the database and turns them into a handy format
if ($testing['prim']){// Checks to see if table prim exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM prim"; // Pulling all info again after cleaning
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('err11');
    $_e = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){// Cycle through enteries to see what rooms are up
        $_e = $_e . "<a href='' onclick='join(" . $row['room'] . ");'>" . $row['teach'] ."</a><br>";
    }
}else $_e = "Sorry no rooms are open";
mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function join(er) {
    alert('ffs is this even firing');//this is a debug statement i was using... it was firing
    //THE LINE BELOW DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK
    document.location = "http://***late edit to get rid of the web address lol sorry***start.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value + "&room=" + er;
    //THE LINE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK
}
</script>
<title>Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
Name:<input type="text" id='name' name="name"><br><?php echo $_e ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried many different small variations like window.location window.location.href etc etc.. also messed with returns and just driving me nuts
Grateful for any help and you folks have a nice day

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: will check into it tyvm.  Always eager to learn something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` will open a new window for you. (see http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml )

Alternatively you could set the href and use `target="_blank"`. That way you don't have to use javascript so it's more accessible.

Comment: window.open did work and did take them to the next page but is there anyway i can do it without having to pop out a new window?

Comment: Can't you just set the link as the href? It doesn't seem to need anything done to it by the javascript. `window.location` should redirect the page without opening a new one.

Comment: I do not know how you would do that and be able to add the """name=" + document.getElementById("name").value""" part into the address

Comment: I didn't see the 'name' part, I should probably concentrate more. window.location('blah blah blah') should work.

Comment: it doesn't when i try window.location it just sits there doing nothing same as document.location.  It is just not letting the redirect go through but allows window.open it opens a new window and everything continues to work just fine.  Only hoping to not have to do the new window now.

Comment: Just had another thought. The link and input could be in a form which would create the link so `<form method='GET' action='super secret link ;)'>Name:<input type="text" id='name' name="name"><input type="hidden" name="room" value="<?php echo $row['room']; // or $room set earlier ?>" /><input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['teach']; // or teach set earlier ?>" /></form>`

Comment: Yeah i think i am going to go with that Qoop.  I use a form for when the user starts the room just a submit button. This is just the end for connecting to the created room.  And i am starting the think that the browsers just have something against the shady redirect maybe. IDK but will go with that ty all very much for your help

Comment: I just realised that `$_e = $_e . "<a href='' onclick='join(" . $row['room'] . ");'>" . $row['teach'] ."</a><br>";` needs extra "s around the variable so it will be sent to the function as a string rather than a reference to a variable, so "<a href='' onclick='join(\"" . $row['room'] . "\");'>"

Comment: i changed it to (\"" . $row['room'] . "\") but it caused the room to always be room= nothing.  I have also set it up where join() didnt have a param and it would just try taking you to the location of the next page.  It still sat there looking at me silly.  I seriously am starting to think that the browsers might be blocking the shady link.  it works when i add an onclick to a td.

Comment: set the href to `javascript:;` otherwise I think it will be reloading the page rather than doing what you want it to do.

Comment: You....Sir are a beautiful man adding in javascript:; worked.  The line is now $_e = $_e . "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='join(" . $row['room'] . ");'>" . $row['teach'] ."</a><br>";

Answer (score 1):

On first hand I am thinking try

```
<a href='#' onclick=...
```

but I will investigate further.

My thought is to try the following and see if it works.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi');">hello</a>
```

Then at least that will tell you if javascript is working properly on your browser etc.

You could try rename it from join to something another name because join is a javascript function (operating on arrays) maybe its having a conflict?

Comment: Tried that as one of the variations i can post all the different lines i have tried/links to other articles on here i have tried if that will help.  Just didn't want to go on too much

Comment: The javascript function is firing off whenever you click a link that is created with the php it fires off alert('ffs is this even firing');

Comment: you could try alert("http://www.adulted-northtx.org/provingground/start.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value + "&room=" + er); and see what it shows

Comment: it shows correctly.  and bah i need to edit out the address there i think

Comment: assuming the room and name have no spaces or strange characters just A-Za-z0-9 otherwise it needs to be escaped

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: they do not. currently the room is simply a number 1-9 and i am jsut testing it right now with the name abcd. so currently it is trying to do something like this.  "**edited out**.org/provingground/start.php?name=abcd&room=1" used with a few different types of document.location, window.location, window.open... the only one that takes me through is window.open but am hoping to not have to do a popup

Comment: also, add `return false;` at the end of the join function

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and tell me if it works. Then try adding some PHP code to the top and see if it still works.

```
<script>
function test()
{
alert("testing");
document.location = "http://location_edited_out/provingground/start.php?name=abcd&room=1";
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="test()">hi</a>
```

One thing you could try is to move the script out of the "head" section and into the body.

For example:

```
<html>
<head><title>Portal</title>
</head><body>
<script>
function join(er) {
alert('ffs is this even firing');//this is a debug statement i was using... it was firing
//THE LINE BELOW DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK
document.location = "http://***late edit to get rid of the web address lol sorry***start.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value + "&room=" + er;
//THE LINE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK
}
</script>
Name:<input type="text" id='name' name="name"><br><?php echo $_e ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you could try putting the script at the end of the body (after the php echo command).

Also you could try splitting it into two statements maybe it doesn't like doing it on the one line:

```
var url = "http://webaddr.com/start.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value + "&room=" + er;
document.location = url;
```

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3285118.htm

Try  window.location.href or simply, location.href
top.location

?

The following works in internet explorer, having a button instead of an "a href".

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function test()
{
alert("testing");
window.location.assign("http://location_edited_out/provingground/start.php?name=abcd&room=1")
}
</script>

<input type='button' value='Load new document' onclick='test()'>
</body></html>
```

Not sure if this is an option?

So the code is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){// Cycle through enteries to see what rooms are up
    $_e = $_e . "<input type='button' onclick='join(" . $row['room'] . ");' value='" . $row['teach'] ."'><br>";
}
...
function join(er) {
    alert('ffs is this even firing');//this is a debug statement i was using... it was firing
    window.location.assign( "http://***late edit to get rid of the web address lol sorry***start.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value + "&room=" + er);
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Neither of these did the trick.  On the first it popped up testing but sat on the same page after that.  And the second one worked the same as it has been

Comment: missed your last line but i threw it at the end of the script and in its own .js and neither seemed to help

Comment: That is interesting!! Because the first one works for me, I'm using firefox. Maybe the problem only occurs with internet explorer.

Comment: let me bring up firefox real quick. sorry for the sake of quick replies i am only testing chrome/ie9

Comment: The first one did infact work on chrome, ei, and firefox not sure if it was a syntax error on my part or what but the first one was taking them to the other pages.  But would not sure how i could grab the room id's.  Also Qoop said the javascript:; thing and when i added that in it was working perfectly and as intended ty all very much.

Comment: Very sorry for the slow response user1888 but that did work using window.location.assign(). And it did so without the href='javascript:;' with href=# or ''